Unproved proposition about constant probability concerning Wiener processes
At Brzezniak, Zastawniak, Basic Stochastic Processes, p.159 the hint of exercise 6.30 says:
[Given that $V_c(t)=\frac 1c W(c^2t)$ is a Wiener process, where $W(t)$ is a Wiener process too] Deduce that the probability
$$P\{\frac {|W(t)|}{t}>cM~\rm{for~some~} t\in[0,\frac {1}{c^2}]\}$$
is the same for every $c>0$.
(I suppose that $M$ is a positive constant independent of $c$.)
How would we give a strict proof of this proposition?
